# Vertical green bar next to code in GoLand

Tags: ide, jetbrains-ide, goland

How can I get rid of the vertical green bar in the image? I somehow activated it but am unsure how to turn it off. I looked through the settings in preferences menu for code styling, but can't seem to find the right option to get it to go away.

[image: GoLand vertical green bar line to left of code]

Comment: `Preferences | Editor | General | Appearance | Show Indent Guides`?

Comment: nope actually realized it was a vim thing and hitting * got it to go away, but doing the same thing doesn't get it to come back again for some reason